# Button layout_height=wrap_content inside linear layout has height much bigger then wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

I have LinearLayout with TextView and Button. I set layout_height attribute to wrap_content but layout_height has much bigger size. If I remove this button then all is alright. I try to decrease button text size but frame of the button still the same. I don't want hardcode button size. What can be the reason this strange result?

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/contact" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/contact"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                
                        android:text="@string/contact" android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button` has background and other layout properties and does not seem possible to reduce its height.  An option would be to use a `TextView` with custom style and handle click event so that it behaves like a `Button`.

Example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact" />
```

It requires some work and time spent to style the `TextView` properly, but if you have no other choice, it may do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well when using a button, you can manually set the height and width, but I also have not found a set way to reduce the wrap_content size.

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of minimum height of a button. Set `android:minHeight="1dp"` or any other size to make it happen.